# How to take count of records using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table called product like below

```
Product
company_code product_code product_name
100          10           bag
100          10           bag_2
100          10           bag_3
100          20           penci_l
100          20           pencil_1
```

i need output like below

```
company_code product_10 product_20
100          3           2
```

How to write sql query for this based on product_code

Comment: product_10 and product_20 are fixed column or it is dynamic ??

Comment: In a generic case, you are looking for a crosstab, which is not natively supported.  However if you have a fixed set product codes, then there are ways of hacking it to get your results.

Comment: fixed, just to take how many codes available in both something like (product_code) as product_10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following query :

```
select company_code , 
SUM(case when product_code = 10 then 1 else 0 end) as product_10 , 
SUM(case when product_code = 20 then 1 else 0 end) as product_20
from product
group by company_code
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c94ec/1)

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT product_code) FROM Product where product_code = 10;

SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT product_code) FROM Product where product_code = 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation using subquery (because I like them ;):

```
SELECT S.company_code, S.product_code,
    SUM(IF(S.product_code = 10, S.C, 0)) AS `product_10`, 
    SUM(IF(S.product_code = 20, S.C, 0)) AS `product_20` 
FROM (SELECT company_code, product_code, COUNT(*) AS C 
        FROM Product 
        GROUP BY company_code, product_code) AS S
GROUP BY S.company_code;
```

(BTW, one might hope that counting using `COUNT()` might make better use of potential index on (company_code, product_code). Not sure of that, thought...)

Producing ...

```
+--------------+--------------+------------+------------+
| company_code | product_code | product_10 | product_20 |
+--------------+--------------+------------+------------+
|          100 |           10 |          3 |          2 |
|          200 |           10 |          1 |          0 |
|          300 |           20 |          0 |          2 |
+--------------+--------------+------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

...from that dataset:

```
mysql> select * from Product;
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| company_code | product_code | product_name |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|          100 |           10 | bag          |
|          100 |           10 | bag_2        |
|          100 |           10 | bag_3        |
|          100 |           20 | pencil       |
|          100 |           20 | pencil_1     |
|          200 |           10 | bag          |
|          300 |           20 | pencil       |
|          300 |           20 | pencil_1     |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want those columns dynamic (crosstab/pivottable) you can do the following:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(case when product_code = ', product_code,
      ' then 1 else 0 end) as product_', product_code
    )) INTO @sql
FROM product;

SET @sql = 
   CONCAT('SELECT company_code, ',
          @sql,
          ' FROM product',
          ' GROUP BY company_code');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The first statement creates @sql with all the `SUM(xxx` and after that the newly formed sql-statement is executed. It does not matter how many products you have. But remember that if you have lots of products this way of showing is not intuitive.

### [Working SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5cbca/2/5)